# The edit link doesn't appear in a question

Tags: support, questions, editing

I noticed that I don't see the edit link in a question asked 2 hours ago, but I see the link in other questions, including the ones asked less than 2 hours ago.

[Backup software for backing up specific files only](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15271/free-backup-software)

[image: screenshot]

[How do I clone a hard disk excluding some directories?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15275/how-to-clone-a-harddisk-excluding-some-directories)

[image: screenshot]

[Address Book: Is there any way to move the fields up/down?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15276/address-book-is-there-any-way-to-move-the-fields-up-down)

[image: screenshot]
This behavior is not the same I note in other Q&A sites where I don't have the privilege of editing posts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anonymous users are limited to suggesting edits for posts more than 8 hours old.

As a registered user with < 2000 rep you should be able to suggest edits on any post, provided

- the suggested edit queue is not full.
- the post does not already have a suggested edit.

I am guessing it was #2

Comment: It's strange that this answer has not been reported in the Super-drop-down menu.